# LiveData not updating for every list item, only for the last one

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, countdowntimer

I have a string LiveData which is a generated identifier from one of my own methods. My problem is that I have a list in recyclerview and when a countdown timer finish, all of items of the recyclerview must generate an identifier but it only generates the identifier for the last item of the list.

This is what I tried:

```
var userPhone = 0
private fun setUpObservable() {
    myViewModel.apply {
        identifierAction.observe() {response - >
           if(response is IdentifierAction.Identifier)
              handleIdentifier(response.identifier)
        }
    }
}

private fun handleIdentifier(identifier: String) {
    //list using data class with name(String), lastname(String), phone(Int) and identifier(String)
    var myList = MySharedPreference.getMyList(context)
    val itemToOverride = myList.find {
        it.phone == userPhone
    }
    if (itemToOverride != null) {
        MySharedPreference.removeUser(context, itemToOverride)
        itemToOverride.identifier = identifier
        MySharedPreference.addUser(context, itemToOverride)
        myList = MySharedPreference.getMyList(context)
        myAdapter.setList(myList)

    }
}
override fun onFinish(position: Int) {
    //list using data class with name(String), lastname(String), phone(Int) and identifier(String)
    val myList = MySharedPreference.getMyList(context)
    if (position != 1) {
        userPhone = myList[position].phone
        myViewModel.generateIdentifier(IdentifierRequisites(name = myList[position].name, lastname = myList[position].lastname, phone = myList[position].phone))
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(private var list: MutableList <MyUser> = mutableListOf(),private var listener: OnTimerFinishListener) {
    interface OnTimerFinishListener {
        fun onFinish(position: Int)
    }
    private fun startCountDownTimer(myList: MyUser) {
        var timer = object: CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(left: Long) {
                //do something every second
            }

            private fun setList(myList: List <MyUser> ) {
                this.list = myList.sortedBy {
                    it.name
                }.toMutableList()
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
                listener.onFinish(absoluteAdapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private val _identifierAction: MutableLiveData < IdentifierAction > by lazy {
    MutableLiveData < IdentifierAction > ().apply {
        value = IdentifierAction.Init
    }
}
val identifierAction: LiveData < IdentifierAction > get() = _identifierAction
fun generateIdentifier(data: IdentifierRequisites) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = generateIdentifierUseCase.invoke(data)
        _identifierAction.postValue(IdentifierAction.Identifier(response))
    }
}
```

When timer finishes, the method onFinish is called for every item of the list but only the last item is triggering handleIdentifier method. How can I solve this? How can I wait for every item to get the identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably generating fine, it's just that the value of the `LiveData` is updated so quickly that by the time it pushes a new value to observers, it's already been set to the last ID in your list. Like this:

```
class CoolVM : ViewModel() {
    val someLiveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    fun setData(number: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.i("ViewModel", "Updating with number: $number")
            someLiveData.postValue(number)
        }
    }
}

class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    private val model: CoolVM by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        model.someLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { num ->
            Log.i("Observer", "Observer got number: $num")
        }
        (1..5).forEach(model::setData)
    }
}
```

And the log output is

```
Updating with number: 1
Updating with number: 2
Updating with number: 3
Updating with number: 4
Updating with number: 5
Observer got number: 5
```

This is just how `LiveData` works, and I'm not aware of a way to force it to push every update immediately. Its focus is more on *the current value* and it's mostly intended as a way to drive the UI in a reactive way. Since the UI only needs to update every frame, it doesn't need to handle every intermediate value when there are a bunch of updates in rapid succession.

---

I'm no coroutine expert so maybe someone else can provide a better solution, but you could try using a `Channel` (which is like a queue) and `collect` that stream of values as a `Flow`:

```
class CoolVM : ViewModel() {
    val numbers = Channel<Int>()
    
    fun setData(number: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.i("ViewModel", "Updating with number: $number")
            numbers.send(number)
        }
    }
}
```

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
            model.numbers.consumeAsFlow().collect { num ->
                Log.i("Observer", "Observer got number: $num")
            }
        }
    }
    (1..5).forEach(model::setData)
}
```

Which *does* handle each value immediately, in turn

```
Updating with number: 1
Observer got number: 1
Updating with number: 2
Observer got number: 2
Updating with number: 3
Observer got number: 3
Updating with number: 4
Observer got number: 4
Updating with number: 5
Observer got number: 5
```

I'm not 100% sure if that's the right approach or if there are any gotchas to watch out for, if someone knows better let me know!